# using sscanf for boost date

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

I am trying to use sscanf to separate a string that has a boost date. here's the code:

```
 std::sscanf(ss.c_str(),"%ls\t%lf\t%lf",&date1_,&num1_,&num2_);
```

and I get the following error:

```
 warning: format ‘%ls’ expects type ‘wchar_t*’, but argument 3 has type ‘boost::gregorian::date*’
```

can anyone suggest me a fix for this. thx!

Comment: Any specific reason why stream IO cannot be used? It's as simple as `istringstream(ss) >> date1 >> num1 >> num2`

Comment: @Cubbi, that's not working....as Kos mentioned, it's looking for the overloaded operator >>

Comment: Should be serializable via >> and << see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/serialization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done this way. `sscanf` is a C function and can only read primitive types, not class types.

In C++ the guns for reading/writing class types are "streams" and come in `<iostream>` and `<sstream>` headers. They will work if the authors of the Boost library you're using were kind enough to overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` for this class.

If the didn't, then your best shot is to read the date fields (as basic types)  one-by-one and then create a `boost::gregorian::date` object using its constructor.

Comment: got it...I will try that out.